# How do i should to type these props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a to-do list using React, TypeScript and TS is saying that the props "item" and "removeTask" at TodoItems.tsx's component have a "any" type and showing a error. What should i do?

```
//TodoItems.jsx:

import {FaTrash} from 'react-icons/fa';

const TodoItems = ({item, removeTask}) => {

    return (
        <li>{item.task} | <FaTrash onclick={() => removeTask(item.id)} /></li>
    )
}

export default TodoItems;


//App.jsx component:

function App() {

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <form onSubmit={handleInput}>
        <input type="text" value={value}
         onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
         className="input" placeholder="Adicione uma tarefa"/>

        <input type="submit"
        className="button"
        value='Adicionar tarefa'/>
      </form>

      <div className='itensArea'>
        {list.map((item) => <ul>
          <TodoItems key={item.id} item={item} removeTask={removeTask} />
        </ul>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: What is the value of `list`?

Comment: Why pass in both props just to re-use them only in the event handler? you're better off doing: `<TodoItem key={item.id} task={item.task} onIconClick={() => { removeTask(item.id); }} />`. Your child components should be more generalized - try not to repeat passing the same props down multiple levels (called prop drilling) - if you have to, the child component shouldn't need to know the context of the parent (eg instead of an array of `books` it's just an array of `data`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import {FaTrash} from 'react-icons/fa';

interface IListItem {
    task: string;
    id: number;
}

interface TodoItemsProps {
    item: IListItem;
    removeTask: (id: number) => void;
}

const TodoItems = ({item, removeTask}: TodoItemsProps) => {

    return (
        <li>{item.task} | <FaTrash onclick={() => removeTask(item.id)} /></li>
    )
}

export default TodoItems;


//App.jsx component:

function App() {
    const list: IListItem[] = [];
    const removeTask = (id: number) => {
        console.log(id);
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <form onSubmit={handleInput}>
                <input type="text" value={value}
                       onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
                       className="input" placeholder="Adicione uma tarefa"/>

                <input type="submit"
                       className="button"
                       value='Adicionar tarefa'/>
            </form>

            <div className='itensArea'>
                {list.map((item) => <ul>
                    <TodoItems key={item.id} item={item} removeTask={removeTask} />
                </ul>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Sharing an alternative for assigning prop types in component -- `const TodoItems: React.FC<TodoItemsProps> = ({ item, removeTask }) => {`, slightly cleaner imo.